# Typing freezes automatically in chromium

Tags: 12.04, chromium, browser

I use ubuntu 12.04 and chromium 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux). When I try to type anything in search bar of a website, after sometime, it(typing) automatically freezes.

And the typing restarts when i double click on web address bar.

What is the problem?

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not freezing, you might have enabled the Chrome's 'Instant search' feature that will start guessing the query that you are typing.
As it process your typed characters in the search box (universal address bar now in chrome)
it process it, which, based on your system/internet speed takes time.
You can try disabling it in the Chrome settings (Settings-Search-Enable instant for faster searching). Cheers.

Comment: No, I didn't enable the instant search feature. YET when in a search box of a site, say, torrenthound.com I try to type something, it just stops typing automatically.